# jquery animate div left/right if conditions

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

I managed to put together a block of code that animates a div inside a container div based on certain conditions - however my math must be slightly off because it is animating slightly too far to the left. see example @ http://dev.whiteb0x.com/gallery

```
var width = $('#nav').width();
$('#nav').width(width * 2 + 20);

$(".nav-next").click(function () {
    var pos = $('#nav').position();
    var width = $('#nav-viewport').width();
    var width = width * (-1);
    alert(width);
    if (pos.left <= 0 && pos.left > width && !$('#nav').is(':animated')) {
        $('#nav li:first').before($('#nav li:last'));
        $("#nav").animate({"left": "-=300"}, "slow");
    }
});

$(".nav-prev").click(function () {
    var pos = $('#nav').position();
    if (!pos.left <= 0 && !$('#nav').is(':animated')) {
        $('#nav li:first').before($('#nav li:last'));
        $("#nav").animate({"left": "+=300"}, "slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: You are declaring `width` in your inner scope twice.  Not the source of your problem, however.

Comment: Also, the animation doesn't seem to work in Firefox.  I am not sure what is causing that.

Comment: Ah, probably because you are defining both `left` and `right` css on your live page.  You need to always use one or the other, regardless of the direction you are scrolling.  Mixing and matching just causes trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `width` three times which will cause you problem later on. You can reduce it to one variable in your scoped click event and rename it so it doesn't interfere with the `with` declared in the outer scope.

```
var _width = - ($('#nav-viewport').width());
```

Then this condition is so weird:

```
if (!pos.left <= 0 && !$('#nav').is(':animated'))
```

Instead of `!pos.left <= 0` you can just do `pos.left > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

try outterWidth? Likely to solve some of the maths

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Answer (score 0):

You've got two things going on at the same time.  You are moving items from the back to the front, etc, and your are animating.  When you do the front-to-back move, all of your images shift.  On top of that, you are only animating by `300px`, when your `li` elements have a margin of `5px`, which is a total of `160px` for 1 image.  (320 for two, but I don't think you want that):

```
var width = $('#nav').width();
$('#nav').width(width * 2 + 20);

$("#nav").css({
    left: $('#nav').position().left - 160 + 'px' // Give a 1 image "buffer" for shifting left
});

$(".nav-next").click(function() {
    var pos = $('#nav').position();
    if (!$('#nav').is(':animated')) {
        $('#nav li:first').insertAfter($('#nav li:last'));
        $("#nav").css({
            left: pos.left + 160 + 'px'  // Move because we reordered images
        }).animate({
            "left": pos.left
        }, "slow"); // Shift back
    }
});

$(".nav-prev").click(function() {
    var pos = $('#nav').position();
    if (!$('#nav').is(':animated')) {
        $('#nav li:last').insertBefore($('#nav li:first'));
        $("#nav").css({
            left: pos.left - 160 + 'px'  // Move because we reordered images
        }).animate({
            "left": pos.left
        }, "slow"); // Shift back
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/GFx7h/1/

Comment: right this current code was just me at a point where I was frustrated, thanks for your help